# Difference Between Media Plugin and Media Capture Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to record audio from user using cordova. On research I found two plugins which seems to do the job. First [media plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/) and other [media capture plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media-capture/). Now my question is can I record audio from both plugin or the media plugin is only for recording from existing audio file? If I can do recording from both which one should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `media.startRecord` from **the media plugin** allows to record audio from within your application whereas the function `capture.captureAudio` from **media capture plugin** will start the default audio capture app of your device and let you access the recorded data once you exit that app.

So with **media plugin** the user will stay in your UI and with **media capture plugin** the user will switch from your app to a capture app and back to your app.

Comment: OK Thank you. Got it. So I should be able to access recorded audio from both plugin in same way right?